# Does final velocity in projectile motion refer to velocity of an object just before it hits the ground?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, projectile

Say a ball is thrown from a height and it drops to the ground. Would the $v_f$ or final velocity be $0$ or would it be the velocity of the ball just before it hits the ground? If I assume the latter, I get the wrong answer according to my textbook. I have a feeling the textbook is wrong. So, who is right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any task or problem that asks for initial or final values, or any other values for that matter, **must clearly define those values**.

If you are asked to find final velocity, then you need the definition of "final" in that particular scenario.

- Sure, the final velocity could have been defined as the velocity just before impact. Then you'll need a few kinematic equations or alternatively some energy conservation considerations to solve the task.
- Sure, the final velocity could have been defined as the velocity right *after* impact. Then you will also need some momentum conservation considerations or similar to solve the task.
- The final velocity might as well have been defined as the velocity at any chosen later time, e.g. 10 seconds after impact or so. Or 10 seconds before the impact. It depends on the purpose.

You really can't solve a task like this without the task clearly defining what it means by the parameters that it asks for. There is no answer to a question like "*what does this parameter in this textbook problem mean*" apart from the definition that the problem itself gives.

Answer (score 1):

The final velocity refers to the velocity of the ball just before hitting the ground.Please check if you have computed the velocity vector correctly.